# how to get multiple outputs given multiple inputs using scanner

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TomAndJerry {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public String catAndMouse(int x, int y, int z) {
        String result = null;
        int q = 0;
        System.out.println("enter the number of queries");
        q = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            x = sc.nextInt();
            y = sc.nextInt();
            z = sc.nextInt();
        }

        if (Math.abs(x - z) < Math.abs(y - z)) {
            result = "Cat A";
        } else if (Math.abs(x - z) > Math.abs(y - z)) {
            result = "Cat B";
        } else {
            result = "Mouse C";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
        String result = null;
        TomAndJerry tj = new TomAndJerry();
        result = tj.catAndMouse(x, y, z);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

OUTPUT:-

```
 enter the number of queries
                    2
                  1 2 3
                  1 3 2
                 Mouse C
```

I end up getting the output only for the last query/input provided using the scanner. How do i get the output for the remaining queries/input. Thanks for your time in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of this piece of code -

```
System.out.println("enter the number of queries");
        q = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            x = sc.nextInt();
            y = sc.nextInt();
            z = sc.nextInt();
        }
```

You are asking user for a number of queries and then asking for x,y and z that many times in the loop and not processing the values inside the loop.

The sole responsibility of your `catAndMouse` method should be to give a result given the input parameters. So, leave the input taking part to the main class.
You can simplify the code like below:

```
public class TomAndJerry {
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public String catAndMouse(int x, int y, int z) {
        String result;
        if (Math.abs(x - z) < Math.abs(y - z)) {
            result = "Cat A";
        } else if (Math.abs(x - z) > Math.abs(y - z)) {
            result = "Cat B";
        } else {
            result = "Mouse C";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("enter the number of queries");
        int q = sc.nextInt();
        int x , y , z ;
        String result;
        TomAndJerry tj = new TomAndJerry();
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            x = sc.nextInt();
            y = sc.nextInt();
            z = sc.nextInt();
            result = tj.catAndMouse(x, y, z);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use List or String[] instead of simple String object to return multiple Strings out of a function ,
also the if condition needs to be part of the for loop and you need to add the result in the List or the array ,
below is the expected output using List

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public List<String> catAndMouse(int x, int y, int z) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    int q = 0;
    System.out.println("enter the number of queries");
    q = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        x = sc.nextInt();
        y = sc.nextInt();
        z = sc.nextInt();
        if (Math.abs(x - z) < Math.abs(y - z)) {
             results.add("Cat A");
        } else if (Math.abs(x - z) > Math.abs(y - z)) {
             results.add("Cat B");
        } else {
             results.add("Mouse C");
        }
    }


    return results;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    Main tj = new Main();
    List<String> results =  tj.catAndMouse(x, y, z);
    System.out.println(results.toString());
}

}
```

> enter the number of queries 2 
>   1 2 3 
>   1 3 2 
>   [Cat B, Mouse C]